# Quickboocs integration qwc file

Tags: api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I download Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions - Accountant Edition 13.0.Create new company

- Company name:company111
- industry :Art, Writing, or Photography
- company type:Corporation
- tax id #: free
- Legal name: company111
- company111
- zip:08136
- phone:0937631038

then I create new customer with name: `new_cust`

this is sample of `qwc` file

```
< ?xml version="1.0" ?>

< QBWCXML >

< AppName >WCWebService1< /AppName >

< AppID >< /AppID >

< AppURL > http1://localhost/WCWebService/WCWebService.asmx < /AppURL >

< AppDescription >A short description for WCWebService1< /AppDescription >

< AppSupport >http://developer.intuit.com< /AppSupport >

< UserName >iqbal1< /UserName >

< OwnerID >{57F3B9B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D20}< /OwnerID >

< FileID >{90A44FB5-33D9-4815-AC85-BC87A7E7D1EB}< /FileID >

< QBType >QBFS</ QBType >

< Scheduler >

< RunEveryNMinutes >2< /RunEveryNMinutes >

< /Scheduler >

</ QBWCXML>
```

How to create `qwc` file for my company? I want to use this file in `Webconnector!`
What is `AppName,AppURL,AppDescription,AppSupport,UserName,OwnerID,FileID,QBType` for my company or how generate `qwc` file for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are based on the configuration of your QBWC server.

You will need to get this information from the person that set it up.